# chcp 1251. Неужели в unix системах все нормально с русской кодировкой, в отличие от винды, или там есть аналоговая команда?

Tags: linux, windows, кодировка, unix

? В unix-подобных системах что надо использовать вместо chcp 1251? Или там ничего не надо так как проблем нет с кириллицей?

Comment: Везде и всюду, последние лет 15 лучше использовать UTF8, и про остальные кодировки забыть как в страшном сне, в том числе и в "окошках"

Comment: так как исправить конкретно с chcp 1251 в unix подобных дистрибутивах?

Comment: Я пока вопроса не понимаю, что и главное где вы хотите исправить, кодовую таблицу по умолчанию? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7069841/10387878

Comment: "так как исправить конкретно с chcp 1251 в unix подобных дистрибутивах?" - ничего не нужно исправлять.

Comment: https://utf8everywhere.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кодировка в никсах входит в понятие "локаль" (locale). Это, грубо говоря, язык + кодировка + языковые особенности типа "разделитель целой и дробной части"

Задаётся локаль в два шага:

1. В файле `/etc/locale.gen` настраивается список локалей для генерации (+ запуск [locale-gen](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-locale-gen/))
2. Переменными окружения [LC_*](http://hepd.pnpi.spb.ru/%7Eshevel/Book/node21.html) указывается локаль, используемая текущим пользователем.

Следовательно вам надо указать список локалей, потом сгенерировать их, потом указать пользователю (или для системы в целом) используемую локаль.

Посмотреть какая локаль у текущего пользователя можно командой `locale`

Немного другой разговор если у вас есть файл в другой кодировке и надо его посмотреть в текущей. Для этого используется [утилита](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html) `iconv`. Обычно используется как то так: `cat file.txt | iconv -f кодировка | less`

Comment: спасибо, все работает!